# What's relation between Sun-Mercury distance measured on the Earth and that given by Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity

We have two data for the the distance between Mercury and Sun. The first is the real-time observatory one, as NASA website https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/mercury/overview/
gives a distance $ R(T) $ for every second $ T $. The second is that we have from the Schwarzschild metric the radial coordinate $ r(t) $ of a given time coordinate $ t $. I know the proper length and the proper time associated with Schwarzschild coordinates $ r(t) $ and $ t $, but I do not know the relation between data ( $ R(T) $, $ T $ ) measured using apparatus mounted on the Earth and data given by Schwarzschild coordinates ($ r(t) $, $ t $).

Comment: The referenced web site is not a real-time observatory. It instead is displaying a value calculated from a solar system ephemeris, which in turn is calculated by modeling the solar system as Cartesian but with a first order post Newtonian expression for gravitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a seemingly reasonable question, but I think it contains some hidden misconceptions. There is not really any concept in general relativity of a distance between two objects as measured by a distant observer. This is because frames of reference are local things in GR. We don't have a frame of reference that covers both the Earth and Mercury.

In high-precision models of the solar system, various data sources, such as optical and radar measurements, are fitted to a GR-based model. To do the fit, one models things like the time taken for light to propagate. If the model on which the nasa.gov web site is based is this kind of high-precision model, then it's using some coordinate system, which may very well be a Schwarzschild coordinate system.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the Schwartzschild radius for the sun is about 3km, while the surface is at 700,000km, and radius of the orbit of mercury is 65,000,000-ish km?